# How to change the current arrows to point down in a [short] in circuitikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

The following code works great but I want the current arrows for I_a and I_b pointing downward. How can I do this?

(I use the current arrows on the fake `[short]` component to make them at the same y-position; if I put it on the R in leg A and on the `[short]` in leg B they show up at different positions.)

```
\documentclass[border=6mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american, /tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.8cm, font=\sffamily]
    \draw (0,0) to[R=$R_{sa}$] (0,2) to [short, i^= $I_a$]++(0,0) to [Tnigfetd,n=mos1](0,3.5) to [Tnigfetd,n=mos1](0,5.5);
    \draw (2,0) to[short] (2,2) to [short, i^= $I_b$]++(0,0) to [Tnigfetd,n=mos1](2,3.5) to [Tnigfetd,n=mos1](2,5.5);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, the `++(0,0)` was not letting me use `i^<=`. If I change to `++(0,0.01)` or some small token distance, it works ok.

```
\documentclass[border=6mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american, /tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.8cm, font=\sffamily]
    \draw (0,0) to[R=$R_{sa}$] (0,2) to [short, i^<= $I_a$]++(0,0.01) to [Tnigfetd,n=mos1](0,3.5) to [Tnigfetd,n=mos1](0,5.5);
    \draw (2,0) to[short] (2,2) to [short, i^<= $I_b$]++(0,0.01) to [Tnigfetd,n=mos1](2,3.5) to [Tnigfetd,n=mos1](2,5.5);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This might be a bug, because the path-direction could not determined for a zero-length path. But, perhaps this can be fixed a workaround.  I have filled a bug-report and will have a look at it. https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/issues/52 Best regards, Stefan